# Laravel Eloquent: dynamically adding parameters to advanced query

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have an array in Laravel with letters, e.g.

```
$letters = array("E", "T", "R");
```

I now want to add these to an advanced query, so that it ends up like this:

```
Table::where('status', 1)->where(function ($q) {
    $q->where('city', 'like', "E%")
     ->orWhere('city', 'like', "T%")
     ->orWhere('city', 'like', "R%");
});
```

But I am not sure how I can loop through the letters. Things like these fail:

```
Table::where('status', 1)->where(function ($q) {
    foreach ($letters as $letter) {
        $q->where('city', 'like', "{$letter}%")
    }
});
```

The error is:

> Undefined variable: $letters

What syntax to use here?

Comment: Undefined variable: $letters

Comment: So, see @aldrin's answer, but notice that's applying an AND and you want an OR. Anyway, he gave you a good hint to solve part of the problem.

Comment: Thanks, that indeed allowed me to solve it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this will work but try this:

```
Table::where('status', 1)->where(function ($q) use ($letters){    //<== NOTICE  `use`
  foreach ($letters as $key=>$letter) {
    if($key == 0){   // IF 1ST ELEMENT, WE DO A $q->where();
        $q->where('city', 'like', "{$letter}%");    //<== STILL NEED THE ; 
    }else{           // OTHERWISE WE DO AN $q->orWhere();
        $q->orWhere('city', 'like', "{$letter}%");  //<== STILL NEED THE ;
    }
  }
});
```

The `use` keyword will get your outside variable.